# Regex for given log file

Tags: ruby, regex

Hi I need RegEx to parse the following line of log file:

```
2015-07-06 11:07:29 +0950 [ERROR] index=heal-legacy host=imb.asp.com 
com.iml.Keplas.collector.CollectorException: Could not process additional data, connection lost to data collector service
Expected result is :
Time   2015-07-06 11:07:29
Type   ERROR
Index  heal-legacy
Host   imb.asp.com 
Message Could not process additional data, connection lost to data collector service
```

Please help me to get these fields Time, Type([ERROR]),index, host, message.

Comment: Whats your expected output loop like and what you have tried so far?

Comment: You don't really need a regex for this. Log files are space-delimited with a fixed number of columns.

Comment: The reason you have many downvotes is that you are asking us to do your work for you. It is expected that you show a little effort trying to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regular expression:

```
(?<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s+(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+\+\d{4}\s+(?<error>\S+)\s+index=(?<index>\S+)\s+host=(?<host>\S+)\s+(?<message>.*)
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/QqYlnCuH8y)

Comment: I see you already are using the regex. So, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "2015-07-06 11:07:29 +0950 [ERROR] index=heal-legacy host=imb.asp.com 
com.iml.Keplas.collector.CollectorException: Could not process additional data, connection lost to data collector service"
a = s.split(" ", 7)
# => ["2015-07-06", "11:07:29", "+0950", "[ERROR]", "index=heal-legacy", "host=imb.asp.com", "com.iml.Keplas.collector.CollectorException: Could not process additional data, connection lost to data collector service"]
[a.first(3).join(" "), a[3], a[4][/(?<==).+/], a[5][/(?<==).+/], a[6]]
# => ["2015-07-06 11:07:29 +0950", "[ERROR]", "heal-legacy", "imb.asp.com", "\ncom.iml.Keplas.collector.CollectorException: Could not process additional data, connection lost to data collector service"]
```